# Best way to add images to a GUI in Java?

Tags: java, image, user-interface, layout

I have a card project that I am doing and it uses GUI's. I have a JFrame

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Card Game");  
//Splits the Jframe into two sections where the cards will be placed      
//according to what user draws them
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
//The users, with different hands of cards
JPanel user1 = new JPanel();
JPanel user2 = new JPanel();
frame.add(user1);
frame.add(user2);
```

I want to be able to efficiently add/remove cards for each users hand. The maximum amount of cards that a user could draw is 9. Initially the user will start of with two cards and I want to make it so that I can add another card neatly. If the space in the panel runs out the cards should go start forming a row beneath.

How do I achieve this? I was thinking of somehow using JLabels, but don't know if this is a correct way. Also I don't know what layout I should use, so any help/tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

> **EDIT**

Thank you for the help, but I still have a problem. I use the code that 'Lourenco' posted to use as my panel where I add cards. I didn't change it. 
In my GUI class I added

```
MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
public void addPlayerCard(Card c){
myPanel.addCard(c.getImageIcon());//should draw the card into the panel 
}
```

This is how I add my imageicon to the card

```
    java.net.URL imgURL = Card.class.getResource(imgFileName);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        image = new ImageIcon(imgFileName, "");
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + imgFileName);
        image = new ImageIcon();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: It runs and compiles fine but does no paint the image

Comment: Please read the link again. Post *here, for us* an MCVE. *We* need to be able to run the code and see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this class. Its a JPanel, so you can create an instance of MyPanel and add to your JFrame.

To add a card you must create an ImageIcon object [ex: ImageIcon card = new ImageIcon("c:\users\desktop\aceOfSpades.png")].

After creating the ImageIcon object you must call the addCard function and pass the card as argument. The card will be added to the ArrayList of cards and the painel will be repainted. You can manipulate the 2 constants CARD_WIDTH and CARD_HEIGHT and the variables x, y and widthToNextCard in the rapaintComponent method.

This way will give you a lot more freedom to paint the cards the way you want, instead of using a layout with different JLabels.

Good luck ;)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final static int CARD_WIDTH = 50;
    public final static int CARD_HEIGHT = 100;

    private ArrayList<ImageIcon> cardsList;

    public MyPanel() {
        cardsList = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
    }

    public void addCard(ImageIcon newCard) {
        cardsList.add(newCard);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int widthToDrawNextCard = 75;
        int x = 50;
        int y = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < cardsList.size(); i++) {
            ImageIcon card = cardsList.get(i);
            Image image = card.getImage();
            g.drawImage(image, x, y, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, null);
            x = x + widthToDrawNextCard;
        }
    }
}
```